# Converting Decimal to binary

Tags: binary, decimal

I am taking an **image** file and converting it into **binary** format. Then I am converting that binary as a decimal format. But according to my algorithm I want to take **50,000 bits** at a time following I am explaining my algorithm.

1. Read an image file from any programming language.
2. Convert that into binary format(pure 0's and 1's).
3. Take **50,000** bits at a time and convert it into decimal format(here I am taking only 1000 bits right now)
4. Convert that decimal again into again binary format.

Now problem is:

- How can I take 50,000 bits at time to convert that into binary format
- How will I convert that decimal number to binary again.

Here are 2 demos

- Converting Binary to decimal https://repl.it/IHMY/1
- Converting decimal to binary https://repl.it/IHMY

Thanks

Comment: To convert binary string into decimal use. Example `int decimal = Integer.parseInt("101101101010111", 2);`

Comment: To make array with elements 50,000 symbols long from string, use RegEx. For example: `.{50000}` combines with `re.match`

Comment: Thanks, Finally I have done.

Comment: Why? The 50,000 bits are already binary. Converting them to decimal and then to binary just gives you what you started with. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have done please follow following link:

https://repl.it/IHMY/4

```
import math;
binary=0b11111111110110001111111111100001
decimal=int(binary)
print(decimal)
print("{0:#b}".format(decimal))
```